# OpenCV VideoCapture not able to open webcam with FFMPEG

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, webcam

### Environment info:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04
- OpenCV version: 4.3.0
- FFMPEG version: 4.2.1

When I tried to run my webcam with `VideoCapture(0)`, it is working well, no problem. Also when I tried the code below, its working too:

```
    Mat frame;

    VideoCapture cap("/video/mp4/file/path.mp4",CAP_FFMPEG);

    while (1) {

        cap>>frame;

        imshow("window",frame);

        if (cv::waitKey(3) > 0)
            break;
    }
```

Also I tried to run my ip camera with `FFMPEG`, its working too.

### BUT

When I tried to run my webcam with FFMPEG like `VideoCapture(0,CAP_FFMPEG)`, its not working. Is this about the output format of streams? I couldnt figure out this ?

Comment: Have you tried with CAP_ANY preference? In this OpenCV try to open the video with every present backend with OpenCV .